# Bound nodes of a force directed graph on a certain div using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a force directed graph using d3.js. When new nodes are inserted to the graph, the graph starts moving on the white area as shown [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtpBj.png). I would like to pinpoint the nodes (incoming and "old) dynamically in order to avoid problems of "cutting" some nodes of the viewBox, as shown in the image attached. 
Any help?

My code so far is:

```
var w = 550;//1200,
h = 400;//750;

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
                      .scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
                      .on("zoom", zoomed);


function zoomed() {
 container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
var testnode=[];

var color = d3.scale.category20();
var scale = 1200;
var vis = d3.select("#force")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", w) //w
.attr("height", h) //h
.attr("id", "svg")
.attr("group", "svg")
.attr("pointer-events", "all")
.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h) 
.call(zoom)   
.attr("perserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMid meet")
.append('svg:g');


var force = d3.layout.force();

var nodes = force.nodes(),
    links = force.links();

var update = function () {

    var packetsReceivedArray = []

    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 1e-6);

    var link = vis.selectAll("line")
    .data(links, function (d) {
        return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id;
    });

    var scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(links, function(d, i) {
     return d.value;
    }))
    .range([1, 5]);


    var scaleNode = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(nodes, function(d, i) {
        return d.packetsReceived;
    }))
    .range([4, 16]);

    link.enter().append("line")
    .attr("id", function (d) {
        return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id;
    })

            .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
                return scale(d.value) + "px";
            })
            .attr("class", "link");
            link.append("title")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.value;
            });
            link.exit().remove();

            var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(nodes, function (d) {
                return d.id;
            });

            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .call(force.drag);

            nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
            .attr("x", 10)
            .attr("y", ".31em")
            .attr("class", "nodeStrokeClass")
            .attr("data-legend",function(d) {
                if(d.group == 0){
                    return 'Basic Node'
                }
                return 'Other nodes'
           });

             nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
             .attr("class", "textClass")
             .attr("x", 14)
             .attr("y", ".31em")

        legend = vis.append("g")
            .attr("class","legend")
            .attr("transform","translate(900,30)")
            .style("font-size","14px")
            .call(d3.legend)

        node.exit().remove();

        force.on("tick", function () {
            node.attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
            });

            link.attr("x1", function (d) {
                return d.source.x;
            })
            .attr("y1", function (d) {
                return d.source.y;
            })
            .attr("x2", function (d) {
                return d.target.x;
            })
            .attr("y2", function (d) {
                return d.target.y;
            });
        });
    force
        .gravity(.1)
        .charge(-300)
        .friction(0.15)
        .linkDistance(60)
        .size([w - 150, h - 150])
        .start();
        };
```

Comment: You mean bound the layout inside the view box?  [Like this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492)?

Comment: Yes @Mark, this is what I want. I have updated my question by inserting my code. I will check the link provided by you and check if this corrects my problem. Thank you!